# React Native ScrollView with absolute position on Android device is not scrollable

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

First of all I would like to mention that the code works fine on iOS but not on Android.

I'm trying to make my own custom dropdown list.
When you pressing on Input the Dropdown opens just beneath it with position absolute.

You can play around with it here: https://snack.expo.dev/@eko_test/dropdown

and see example snippets below.

```js
<Input
        value={inputValue}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onTouchStart={() => setShowItems((prevState) => !prevState)}
        onTouchEnd={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
        onChangeText={onSearchItem}
      />
      {showItems && (
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.itemsContainer}
          contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 6 }}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        >
          {usedItemList.length > 0 ? (
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.hintText}>Last used</Text>

              <DropdownList
                items={savedItemList}
                onItemSelect={onListItemSelect}
              />

              <View style={styles.separator} />
            </View>
          ) : undefined}

          <DropdownList items={itemList} onItemSelect={onListItemSelect} />
        </ScrollView>
      )}
```

```js
const DropdownList: FC<DropdownListProps> = ({ items, onItemSelect }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <DropdownItemComponent
          key={item.id}
          item={item}
          onItemPress={() => onItemSelect(item)}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

```js
itemsContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 35,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    borderBottomWidth: 1.6,
    borderBottomColor: Colors.green,
    maxHeight: 160,
  },
```

Comment: can put an example on <https://snack.expo.dev> and share it, so we can test you're code and see what's wrong

Comment: @Firstdev I've just updated question and added link to snack.expo.dev/@eko_test/dropdown

Comment: @EKOLX Have you made any progress?

Comment: @TchiteuAbloh, nope, I worked around